# Scroll to wrong field ERROR

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to know how to scroll the page to the wrong field when I submit a form.
I searched high and low and I find many solution with jquery but no solution work as I wish.
I found solution that scroll the page when I submit with success but not when I had error.
To better understand, below my commented source code:

```js
// function that check filled when key up
function checkFilled(variable) {
 var inputVal = document.getElementById(variable).value;
    if (inputVal == "") {
        document.getElementById(variable).style.borderColor = "red";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById(variable).style.borderColor = "green";
    }
}

// function that check email filled
function checkFilledEmail(variable) {
 fld_value = document.getElementById(variable).value;
    is_m_valid = 0;
    if (fld_value.indexOf('@') >= 1) {

        m_valid_dom = fld_value.substr(fld_value.indexOf('@')+1).length;
        
        if (m_valid_dom >= 1) {

         is_m_valid = 1;
        }
        
    }
    if (is_m_valid) {
       document.getElementById(variable).style.borderColor = "green";
    } else {
       document.getElementById(variable).style.borderColor = "red";
    }
    
}


    $(function(){
        $("#contact").submit(function(event){
            var nom        = $("#nom").val();
            var sujet      = $("#sujet").val();
            var email      = $("#email").val();
            var message    = $("#message").val();
            var dataString = nom + sujet + email + message;
            var msg_all    = "Merci de remplir tous les champs";
            var msg_alert  = "Merci de remplir le champs: ";
            $("#msg_all").html('');
            $("#msg_nom").html('');
            $("#msg_email").html('');
            $("#msg_sujet").html('');
            $("#msg_message").html('');
            
            if(dataString  == "")
            {
                document.getElementById('nom').style.borderColor = "red";
                document.getElementById('email').style.borderColor = "red";
                document.getElementById('sujet').style.borderColor = "red";
                document.getElementById('message').style.borderColor = "red";
                
            }
            else if(nom == "")
            {
                
                document.getElementById('nom').style.borderColor = "red";
                 
                /*
                
                //In that position, this code didn't work but above with ajax it worked very well                     
                        $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: $("#msg_nom").offset().top
                        }, 500);
                */

// => I want to find code that do the same action as scrollTop but with javascript.
               
            }
            
            else if(email == "")
            {
               
                document.getElementById('email').style.borderColor = "red";
            }
             else if(sujet == "")
            {
                
                document.getElementById('sujet').style.borderColor = "red";
            }

            else if(message == "")
            {
                
                document.getElementById('message').style.borderColor = "red";
            }
            else
            {
                
                $.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    url: $(this).attr("action"),
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success : function(){
                        $("#msg_all").html(" <p style='text-align:center; margin-bottom:40px;'>Formulaire bien envoyé</p> ");
                        $(':input','#contact')
         .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
         .val('');
         $("#msg_nom").html('');
         $("#msg_email").html('');
         $("#msg_sujet").html('');
         $("#msg_message").html('');
         document.getElementById('nom').style.borderColor = "";
                        document.getElementById('email').style.borderColor = "";
                        document.getElementById('sujet').style.borderColor = "";
                        document.getElementById('message').style.borderColor = "";
                        
                      
                    //In that position, this code work and the screen scroll   
                      
                      /*
                        $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: $("#msg_nom").offset().top
                        }, 500);
                      */
      
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        $("#msg_all").html("<p style='text-align:center; margin-bottom:40px;'>Erreur dappel, le formulaire ne peut pas fonctionner</p>");
                      document.getElementById('nom').style.borderColor = "";
                        document.getElementById('email').style.borderColor = "";
                        document.getElementById('sujet').style.borderColor = "";
                        document.getElementById('message').style.borderColor = "";
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
```

```css
element.style {
display: block;
height: auto;
}

.field-style {
width: 50%;
height: 46px;
margin-bottom: 26px;

background-color: transparent;

  }

.label-style {
margin-bottom: 9px;
font-family: Merriweather, serif;
line-height: 17px;
font-weight: 400;
  display:block;
}

element.style {
border-color: red;
}

.simple-button {
display: block;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="process.php" id="contact" method="POST">
       
       
            <label  for="nom" class="label-style">Nom</label>
            <input class="w-input field-style" id="nom" name="nom" onkeyup="checkFilled('nom');" type="text">
       
            <span id="msg_nom"></span>
       
        
            <label for="email" class="label-style">Email</label>
            <input class="w-input field-style" id="email" name="email"  onkeyup="checkFilledEmail('email');" type="email">
            <span id="msg_email"></span>

            <label for="sujet" class="label-style" >Sujet</label>
            <input class="w-input field-style" id="sujet" name="sujet" onkeyup="checkFilled('sujet');" type="text">
            <span id="msg_sujet"></span>
        
            <label class="label-style" for="message">Message</label>
            <textarea class="w-input messageform" id="message" name="message" onkeyup="checkFilled('message');"  rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
            <span id="msg_message"></span>
        
        
            <span id="msg_all"></span>
            <input class="w-button simple-button" type="submit" value="Envoyer" />
        
    </form>
```

Any idea how can I achieve my aim? or any keyword that allow me to keep search.

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote is correct (the code that scrolls the page and doesn't work as you wrote in the comment), the problem is it's not executed because the first condition (dataString  == "") is true.

Comment: The commented code must execute when  (dataString == " "). The error is identified when (dataString == " ") !!! I don't understand what did you mean !!!

Comment: The commented code is in the block under this condition :

else if(nom == "")

and this condition is not even checked because the one before it: if (dataString == "") is true.